# How to use ADB over WiFi with dynamic IP for automated testing

Tags: android, adb, dynamic-ip, adbwireless

My android phones' IP changes once a day randomly.
However, I want to automatically apply it to my server computer which is conducting automated testing every day.

Is there any way I can prohibit android phones from changing IP?
If not, should I make an application to receive the broadcasting of changed IP and apply it?

Comment: This sounds more like a networking problem instead of an android problem.
You can assign a static IP to your wifi devices in your router's settings.

You can also set an IP in android manually in the wifi settings instead of using the IP which is assigned to your phone via HDCP.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann, thanks for the information. I will try those and leave a comment here.